# How to set cell value by id NPOI ,C#

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

Please help me. I have a question for npoi c#

Generally to set value in npoi is

```
sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
IRow row = sheet.GetRow(0);
ICell cell = rowA.GetCell(0);
cell.setvalue("Sometime");
```

but, Can I set value by cell name from excel?  **example**

at cell **A1**  set name to **salary**

and code like this

```
    row = sheet.GetRow(0);
    cell = row.getID(A1/salary); //get A1 or salary
    cell.setvalue(5000); // result in cell A1 = 5000
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get cell by name only by the reference with using `CellReference`.

```
var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
var cr = new CellReference("A1");
var row = sheet.GetRow(cr.Row);
var cell = row.GetCell(cr.Col);
cell.setvalue(5000);
```

Comment: ok i  was try by your code. sadly that can not get cell by name

Comment: what different between cellrefernce vs celladdress

Comment: It will not work. CellReference only parse cell address "A1" and gets the appropriate row and column index.